# Why data from local Json file doesn't work on gh page?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

So, I have json file with some data, and some parameters from this file I'm using in my react app. But when I published it on GH page, It doesn't work...

```
componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get('/phone.json').then(({data}) => {
      this.setState({
        phone: data
      })
    })
  }
```

```
{this.state.phone.map((p,index) => (<div className='model' key={index}>{p.body.model}</div>))}
```

Comment: Maybe because you made it an absolute path. Add a dot before the slash maybe?

Comment: if it is a local json file there is no need to fetch it. you can just import it as a module

Comment: @Ajeet Shah Yes

Comment: @Ajeet Shah Yes

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Thank you, I forgot about dot.. You can add the answer..

Comment: @AjeetShah thank you for your attention, i solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just forgot to put the dot before:

```
/phone.json
```

```
componentDidMount() {
    Axios.get('./phone.json').then(({data}) => {
      this.setState({
        phone: data
      })
    })
  }
```

Thank you guys for your attention.